# ADB is not detecting my phone (Micromax A35) in CENTOS

Tags: adb, linux, usb-drivers, micromax-a35

ADB is not listing my Micromax a35, but it detects Samsung phones.

How can I install Micromax a35 drivers in **CENTOS**?

Comment: Have you tried Zadig? Don't know if they have that for CentOS though.

Comment: No.. But Zadig is not available for CentOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No drivers are needed for ADB devices in linux. The ADB binary uses [libusb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libusb) to access the device. All you need to do is add device's USB vendor ID to `~/.android/adb_usb.ini`

```
mkdir -p ~/.android
find -L /sys/bus/usb/devices -maxdepth 2 -path "*/modalias" -printf "%h\t" -exec cat {} \; | awk -F: "/icFFisc42ip01/{print\$1}" | xargs -i cat {}/idVendor | sort -u | xargs -i echo "0x"{} >> ~/.android/adb_usb.ini
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb devices
```

Comment: How to get the vendor id ?